# how to bind checkboxes in ember with a list

Tags: checkbox, ember.js

I have a model where I have a list of all countries as below -

```
[{"code":"US", "name":"USA"}]
```

selected counties will be pass on as a list like below -

```
["US", "CA"]
```

my template has a list of checkboxes like below -

```
{{#validatable-control label="Countries" error=errors.Countries}}
    {{log "All: "}} {{log model.AllCountries}}
    {{log "Selected: "}} {{log model.Countries}}
    {{#each model.AllCountries as |country|}} {{log "country: "}} {{log country.Code}} {{log country.Name}}
        <label class="checkbox-inline">{{input type="checkbox" checked=(mut (get model.Countries country.Code))}}{{country.Name}}</label>
    {{/each}}
{{/validatable-control}}
```

the code above doesn't work as intended and I am trying to figure out how to configure the checkbox to achieve what I need. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`country.Code` => replace it with `country.code` - propertyName is case sensitive.

Introduced `isSelected` property for every country,

```
{{#each model.AllCountries as |country|}} 
 <label class="checkbox-inline">
  {{input type="checkbox" checked=(mut (get country 'isSelected'))}}      {{country.name}} 
 </label>
{{/each}}
```

I implemented in [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b0e9cab25764e50c122ca482776bdae3?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C), have a look at it.